# How to: CUDA IFFT

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda, cufft

In Matlab when, I enter a one dimensional array of complex numbers, I have an output of arrays with real numbers of same size and same dimension.
Trying to repeat this in CUDA C, but have different output.
Can you please help? In Matlab, when I enter ifft(array)

*My arrayOfComplexNmbers:*

```
[4.6500 + 0.0000i   0.5964 - 1.4325i   0.4905 - 0.5637i   0.4286 - 0.2976i   0.4345 - 0.1512i   0.4500 + 0.0000i   0.4345 + 0.1512i  0.4286 + 0.2976i   0.4905 + 0.5637i   0.5964 + 1.4325i]
```

*My arrayOfRealNumbers:*

```
[ 0.9000    0.8000    0.7000    0.6000    0.5000    0.4000    0.3000    0.2000    0.1500    0.1000]
```

When I enter `ifft(arrayOfComplexNmbers)` in Matlab, my output is `arrayOfRealNumbers`. 
Thank you!
This is my CUDA code for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"

#define NX 256
#define NY 128
#define NRANK 2
#define BATCH 1
#define SIGNAL_SIZE 10

typedef float2 Complex;
__global__ void printCUDAVariables_1(cufftComplex *cudaSignal){
int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;    
printf("COMPLEX CUDA %d %f %f \n", index, cudaSignal[index].x, cudaSignal[index].y);
}

__global__ void printCUDAVariables_2(cufftReal *cudaSignal){
int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
printf("REAL CUDA %d %f \n", index, cudaSignal);
}


int main() {
cufftHandle plan;
//int n[NRANK] = { NX, NY };
Complex *h_signal = (Complex *)malloc(sizeof(Complex)* SIGNAL_SIZE);
float *r_signal = 0;
if (r_signal != 0){
    r_signal = (float*)realloc(r_signal, SIGNAL_SIZE * sizeof(float));
}
else{
    r_signal = (float*)malloc(SIGNAL_SIZE * sizeof(float));
}
int mem_size = sizeof(Complex)* SIGNAL_SIZE * 2;

h_signal[0].x = (float)4.65;
h_signal[0].y = (float)0;

h_signal[1].x = (float)0.5964;
h_signal[1].y = (float)0;

h_signal[2].x = (float)4.65;
h_signal[2].y = (float)-1.4325;

h_signal[3].x = (float)0.4905;
h_signal[3].y = (float)0.5637;

h_signal[4].x = (float)0.4286;
h_signal[4].y = (float)-0.2976;

h_signal[5].x = (float)0.4345;
h_signal[5].y = (float)-0.1512;

h_signal[6].x = (float)0.45;
h_signal[6].y = (float)0;

h_signal[7].x = (float)0.4345;
h_signal[7].y = (float)-0.1512;

h_signal[8].x = (float)0.4286;
h_signal[8].y = (float)0.2976;

h_signal[9].x = (float)0.4905;
h_signal[9].y = (float)-0.5637;

h_signal[10].x = (float)0.5964;
h_signal[10].y = (float)1.4325;
//for (int i = 0; i < SIGNAL_SIZE; i++){
//  printf("RAW %f %f\n", h_signal[i].x, h_signal[i].y);
//}
//allocate device memory for signal
cufftComplex *d_signal, *d_signal_out;
cudaMalloc(&d_signal, mem_size);    
cudaMalloc(&d_signal_out, mem_size);
cudaMemcpy(d_signal, h_signal, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
printCUDAVariables_1 << <10, 1 >> >(d_signal);
//cufftReal *odata;
//cudaMalloc((void **)&odata, sizeof(cufftReal)*NX*(NY / 2 + 1));

//cufftPlan1d(&plan, SIGNAL_SIZE, CUFFT_C2R, BATCH);    
cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);
cufftExecC2C(plan, d_signal, d_signal_out, CUFFT_INVERSE);
//cufftExecC2R(plan, d_signal, odata);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
printCUDAVariables_1 << <10, 1 >> >(d_signal_out);
//printCUDAVariables_2 << <10, 1 >> >(odata);
//cudaMemcpy(h_signal, d_signal_out, SIGNAL_SIZE*2*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cufftDestroy(plan);
cudaFree(d_signal);
cudaFree(d_signal_out);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most of the concurrent systems do not specify the order of thread execution. It is a basic concept and has nothing to do specifically with CUDA. Concretely, your assumption that threads will be executed in sequential order of thread IDs (e.g. 0, 1, 2, ..., n_threads) is wrong. (1) copy data to host and print it there; (2) implement [proper error checking for CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and [cuFFT](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#cufftresult) APIs. Then we can start talking business.

Comment: Thank you, but my CUDA output is totally different from MATLAB. Please run my code. This case is not about the order, but about the ifft results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When computing `ifft` with MATLAB, the default behavior is as follows:

- No zero padding of the input signal
- No scaling of the output signal

Your CUFFT code is correct in flow, but a bit different parameters compared to MATLAB are causing the current output.

- The `NX` constant to be specific is causing the input signal to be
  zero-padded to a length of 256. To achieve MATLAB's behavior, keep `NX` equal to `SIGNAL_SIZE`.
- CUFFT multiples the output signal values with the length of the input signal. You have to divide the output values with `SIGNAL_SIZE`  to get the actual values.
- Another important issue is that you are performing out-of-bound access at the time of initializing the input signal. The signal length is 10, but you are initializing the value at 10th index which is out of bound. I assume that this may be due to confusion caused by 1 based indexing of MATLAB. The input signal must be initialized from `0` to `SIGNAL_SIZE-1` indices only.
- It is not recommended to visualize the signal using a CUDA kernel as the printing may be out of order. You should copy the results back to host and print them serially.

Here is the fixed code which is providing the same output as MATLAB.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"

#define NX 10
#define NY 1
#define NRANK 1
#define BATCH 1
#define SIGNAL_SIZE 10

typedef float2 Complex;  

int main() 
{
cufftHandle plan;
//int n[NRANK] = { NX, NY };
Complex *h_signal = (Complex *)malloc(sizeof(Complex)* SIGNAL_SIZE);
float *r_signal = 0;
if (r_signal != 0)
{
    r_signal = (float*)realloc(r_signal, SIGNAL_SIZE * sizeof(float));
}
else
{
    r_signal = (float*)malloc(SIGNAL_SIZE * sizeof(float));
}
int mem_size = sizeof(Complex)* SIGNAL_SIZE;

h_signal[0].x = (float)4.65;
h_signal[0].y = (float)0;

h_signal[1].x = (float)0.5964;
h_signal[1].y = (float)-1.4325;

h_signal[2].x = (float)0.4905;
h_signal[2].y = (float)-0.5637;

h_signal[3].x = (float)0.4286;
h_signal[3].y = (float)-0.2976;

h_signal[4].x = (float)0.4345;
h_signal[4].y = (float)-0.1512;

h_signal[5].x = (float)0.45;
h_signal[5].y = (float)0.0;

h_signal[6].x = (float)0.4345;
h_signal[6].y = (float)0.1512;

h_signal[7].x = (float)0.4286;
h_signal[7].y = (float)0.2976;

h_signal[8].x = (float)0.4905;
h_signal[8].y = (float)0.5637;

h_signal[9].x = (float)0.5964;
h_signal[9].y = (float)1.4325;

printf("\nInput:\n");
for(int i=0; i<SIGNAL_SIZE; i++)
{
    char op = h_signal[i].y < 0 ? '-' : '+';
    printf("%f %c %fi\n", h_signal[i].x/SIGNAL_SIZE, op, fabsf(h_signal[i].y/SIGNAL_SIZE ) );
}

//allocate device memory for signal
cufftComplex *d_signal, *d_signal_out;
cudaMalloc(&d_signal, mem_size);    
cudaMalloc(&d_signal_out, mem_size);
cudaMemcpy(d_signal, h_signal, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


//cufftPlan1d(&plan, SIGNAL_SIZE, CUFFT_C2R, BATCH);    
cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);

cufftExecC2C(plan, d_signal, d_signal_out, CUFFT_INVERSE);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaMemcpy(h_signal, d_signal_out, SIGNAL_SIZE*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


printf("\n\n-------------------------------\n\n");
printf("Output:\n");
for(int i=0; i<SIGNAL_SIZE; i++)
{
    char op = h_signal[i].y < 0 ? '-' : '+';
    printf("%f %c %fi\n", h_signal[i].x/SIGNAL_SIZE, op, fabsf(h_signal[i].y/SIGNAL_SIZE ) );
}

cufftDestroy(plan);
cudaFree(d_signal);
cudaFree(d_signal_out);

return 0;
}
```

The output is still in complex form but the imaginary components are close to zero. Also, the difference in precision of real component is because MATLAB uses double precision by default while this code is based on single precision values.

---

Compiled and tested with following command on Ubuntu 14.04, CUDA 8.0:

> nvcc -o ifft ifft.cu -arch=sm_61 -lcufft

Compared output with MATLAB 2017a.

## Program Output:

```
Input:
0.465000 + 0.000000i
0.059640 - 0.143250i
0.049050 - 0.056370i
0.042860 - 0.029760i
0.043450 - 0.015120i
0.045000 + 0.000000i
0.043450 + 0.015120i
0.042860 + 0.029760i
0.049050 + 0.056370i
0.059640 + 0.143250i


-------------------------------

Output:
0.900000 - 0.000000i
0.800026 - 0.000000i
0.699999 - 0.000000i
0.599964 - 0.000000i
0.500011 + 0.000000i
0.400000 + 0.000000i
0.299990 + 0.000000i
0.199993 + 0.000000i
0.150000 + 0.000000i
0.100018 - 0.000000i
```

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that cufft does *not* normalize during fft operations, whereas Matlab will normalize by SIGNAL_SIZE when it does an ifft.

Comment: @Michael Yes, indeed, *normalize* is more appropriate word for the division step.